I'm a beginner in web development and I've been struggling with CSS positioning. I use a mix of Bootstrap and CSS
I'm a beginner in web development and I've been struggling with CSS positioning. I've been trying to place a Bootstrap profile button to the right of a menu, both aligned to the left side of the screen.
I've tried using CSS float, position, and margin properties, but I can't seem to get it right. I understand only the basics of CSS and would appreciate some guidance.
Here's a snippet of my sidebar component and CSS:
Sidebar.jsx:
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <button className="toggle-btn">
        Profile
      </button>
      <Dropdown>
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="secondary" id="dropdown-basic">
          Menu
        </Dropdown.Toggle>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Item 1</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Item 2</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Item 3</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-4">Item 4</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;

SidebarStyles.css:
.sidebar {
  position: relative;
}

.toggle-btn {
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu-list {
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.sidebar.open .menu-list {
  display: block;
}

I'm using Bootstrap for some parts of my project, which I suspect might be causing some conflicts with my CSS.
Any help or suggestions on how to achieve the desired layout would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
I have tried asking chat gpt for help and searched Google, but I couldn't solve it; I am not good in CSS, so I might have messed up some parts

have you tried adding !important at the end of the CSS-properties? because Bootstrap may sometimes apply its own CSS-styles over yours
